# How to set and get a variable in tesseract using C++

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I have a quick question: How to I get the variable in tesseract using C++.

For example I want to set `"load_system_dawg" to false`

```
`tesseract.setVariable("load_system_dawg",?);`
```

Is ? = 0 and 1, or "true" and "false"?

And also how to check the settings of a variable?

```
`tesseract.getBoolVariable("load_system_dawg");`
or 
`tesseract.getVariableAsString("load_system_dawg");`
```

In all my cases and attempts the code breaks.

[Documentation Tesseract GetBoolVariable](http://tesseract-ocr.github.io/a00614.html#ac5e219cbaa2c19c67ccef3246ff838a6)

*EDIT*

I am able to get a variable, but why is get after set not possible.

```
tess.SetVariable("load_punc_dawg", "0");
tess.SetVariable("load_punc_dawg", "false");
bool result = false;
tess.GetBoolVariable("load_punc_dawg", &result);
```

But the `result = true.`

    bool thisOne = tess.GetBoolVariable("load_punc_dawg", &result);

```
returns `"thisOne" = true`, and `"result" = true"`
```

And To check the results I am debugging through the code.

Comment: did you try `tess.SetVariable("load_punc_dawg", "false");`, i.e. "false" instead of "0" ?

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: ..just to be sure.. you have something like `if (result) {std::cout << "damn it didnt work" << std::endl;}` after the call to getBoolVariable ?

Comment: check also the return value of `GetBoolVariable`. If the value was set succesful it returns true (false if it could not find "load_punc_dawg")

Comment: as mentioned before, I do not know ocr. However, now I am interested in the question... for complete diagnostics you should also look at the return value of `SetVariable`

Comment: OK, will do that tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that seems to be very interesting. Set the parameter at the tesseract initialization works for me at the moment.

```
GenericVector<STRING> pars_vec;
pars_vec.push_back("load_punc_dawg");

GenericVector<STRING> pars_values;
pars_values.push_back("0"); //"false"

tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY, NULL, 0, &pars_vec,
            &pars_values, false);

bool result = false;
bool thisOne = tess.GetBoolVariable("load_punc_dawg", &result);

returns "thisOne" = true and "result" = false
```

[Source found here](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version)

Comment: Looks like some parameters can only be set during the call to Init().  Source:  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ControlParams

Answer (score 1):

I do not know ocr, but simply by reading the [doc](http://tesseract-ocr.github.io/a00614.html#ac5e219cbaa2c19c67ccef3246ff838a6) I found out, that....

The function to get the bool variable has this signature:

```
bool GetBoolVariable (const char * name,bool * value) const
```

So you have to call it like this:

```
bool result;
tesseract.GetBoolVariable("name",&result);
```

The setVariable takes a `const char *` as second argument. Thus your `?` should be either `"0"`/`"1"` or `"true"`/`"false"` (but not `0`/`1` or `true`/`false` and I am pretty sure that both variants will work).

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I will try and response immediately.